# AAPT: error: attribute android:raidus not found

Tags: android-studio

[image: picture of error with my code]

Hello, I'm trying to create a button with rounded edges, so I set the radius to 22dp, but when I ran it it gave me this error: ERROR:C:\Users\home\AndroidStudioProjects\music\app\src\main\res\drawable\btn_bg.xml:9: AAPT: error: attribute android:raidus not found.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your shape attribute `android:shape="rectangle"` is out side of the shape use it like below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

      <solid android:color="@color/white" />
      <corners android:radius="22dp" />
</shape>
```